# Python: Adding dictionary value pair only if they are Unique. If they are already present, I need to print the dictionay values

Tags: python

class VoqConnIngressList:

```
def addEntry(self,voqID, core, nofVoqs, remoteVOQconnector, remoteModID, unitID):
    key = [voqID+","+remoteModID]
    if key not in self.dictOfVoqs:
        self.dictOfVoqs[voqID+","+remoteModID] = [voqID, core, nofVoqs, remoteVOQconnector, remoteModID, unitID]

    else:
        print("Entry already present")
```

`voqConnIngressList.addEntry(10, 30, 40, 50, 60, 1)`

`voqConnIngressList.addEntry(10, 30, 40, 50, 60, 1)`

In this core If it detects duplicates. then I should print message saying it is duplicate.

When I types this code, I am getting the below error

> if key not in self.dictOfVoqs: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: You don't even need to make a string to index a dictionary, you can use tuples: `dictOfVoqs[voqID, remoteModID]`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need those square braces `[]` for defining your `key` variable. It becomes a list when you add those. A membership check on the dict will run through the dictionary keys of which a list is not hashable and does not qualify as a candidate/potential key:

```
>>> [] in {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Just replace that line with:

```
key = voqID + "," + remoteModID
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second line of your code `key = [voqID+","+remoteModID]`, you are making the key a list. Keys cannot be lists. Remove the square brackets. `key = voqID+","+remoteModID`

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it's a difference between the python versions, but...

A key in a dictionary needs to be hashable, and a list is not hashable (but a string would be).
Your key 
`key = [voqID+","+remoteModID]`
is a list, because of the `[]`
Just make it a string.